# How to use the variable from a <script></script> after adding it?

Tags: reactjs

http://cloudinary.com/blog/how_to_build_an_image_library_with_react_cloudinary

(except I used create-react-app instead of manually configuring webpack)

Where the script is added to  of index.html:

```
<script src="//widget.cloudinary.com/global/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and then the functionality is included in a component:

```
uploadWidget() {
    cloudinary.openUploadWidget({ cloud_name: 'CLOUD_NAME', upload_preset: 'PRESET', tags:['xmas']},
        function(error, result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
}
```

However I am getting the error: `'cloudinary' is not defined`

Is `cloudinary` supposed to be available there after simply adding the script? Am I missing a step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to access it through `window.cloudinary`. Also make sure that the script is included before your React script is included.

Comment: It was `window.cloudinary`. Appreciate it!